# jQuery OR operator in an IF statement checking if either text field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have short jQuery code trying to check whether either of the text fields is empty. If *either* is empty then the form won't be submitted. Unfortunately, it submits only if both text fields are filled. That should happen if I use the AND operator, but I am using OR operator. What is the explanation?

The form fields

```html
<form method="post"
      name="customerData"
      action="ccavRequestHandler.php"
      id="merchantFORM"
      role="form">

      <!-- New item -->
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
              <h6>Passport</h6>
              <input class="form-control" id="paspatou" type="text" name="merchant_param4" />
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- New item -->
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
              <h6>Unique ID Number</h6>
              <input class="form-control" id="urno" type="text" name="merchant_param3" />
          </div>
      </div>
```

The text field id names are "paspatou" and "urno".

I am also checking whether one of the radio buttons are checked or not and that works fine too as I have to detect whether the donor is local or outstation. The only issue is detecting that only one field has to be filled, not both.

```
if ($("input[name='donationfrom'][value='no']").prop("checked")) {

    $("#merchantFORM").on('submit', function (e) {
        if ($("input[name='donationfrom'][value='no']").prop("checked")) {
            if (($("#paspatou").val().length <= 0) || ($("#urno").val().length <= 0)) {
                alert("Please fill either Passport or Unique ID Number");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should use console.log to check where is your code going.
I think it's because the first condition (donationfrom) is invalid

Comment: Try it without the `if ($("input[name='donationfrom'][value='no']").prop("checked")) {` line

Comment: So the two fields are *only* required when donationFrom/no is ticked.

Comment: Next step is to add a [mcve] example.   Edit and click `[<>]` to create a snippet, include all the relevant html (the form, the checkbox, the 2 inputs and a button).

Comment: It may be the wording of the question - the `alert` indicates that it should be either = "only one" not just "either" = "one or both" and you also stated "*only one field has be to be filled **not both**"*

Comment: *it submits only if both text fields are filled* - *should use AND* - yes, if you're checking if both fields are *filled* - but you're not.  You're checking if they're empty - and you don't want "both" anything - (it appears) you want one filled and one not filled, so use `if (($("#paspatou").val().length === 0) === ($("#urno").val().length === 0))` so they're not both empty/both with a value.

Comment: Please confirm that you only want one value - either passport *or* number.   Not that "at least one (or both)" should be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the code in your inner *if* statement. You actually need *&&* here as you want to show the alert when both fields are empty.

```
if (($("#paspatou").val().length <= 0) && ($("#urno").val().length <= 0)) {
    alert("Please fill either Passport or Unique ID Number");
    return false;
}
```

Other solution, if you want to keep the OR logic is to change your code like so:

```
  $("#merchantFORM").on('submit', function (e) {
    if ($("input[name='donationfrom'][value='no']").prop("checked")) {
        if (($("#paspatou").val().length > 0) || ($("#urno").val().length > 0)) {
            return true;
        }

        alert("Please fill either Passport or Unique ID Number");
        return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: I changed the condition because I switched the logic in the IF to return true and if the condition is not met you will go to the part with the alert.

Comment: thanks it works, to get clarity why was a true value returned within the OR statement?